# MediaPLayer gets errors

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I used `MediaPlayer` with stream music from http

I have 2 questions:

1. Is `MediaPlayer` play music in stream or it downloads music and play after it?
2. Why i have this error in `LogCat`:

   > MediaPlayer(3438): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

   But after sec or 2 music starts to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It uses progressive streaming. See http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html
- From what I see it is a debug statement and not an error. This is where it comes from: `MediaPlayer.java: Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side");`. It seems that it is trying to find the URI locally and only when not found sets the media URI in the datasource (read - opens network connection).

Comment: Oh thanks, it means there is no problems? :)
How to optimize it? Because it's 2 secs between button pressed and music started

Comment: Yes, the debug statement is not a problem.

Comment: i do the same but still i cant play .mp4 video 08-12 14:37:30.599: D/MediaPlayer(23633): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side 08-12 14:37:33.095: E/MediaPlayer(23633): error (1, -2147483648) 08-12 14:37:33.096: E/MediaPlayer(23633): Error (1,-2147483648) 08-12 14:37:33.096: D/VideoView(23633): Error: 1,-2147483648 got this error